# C++ and Android NDK interaction for COCOS2D-X

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I know that using COCOS2D-X I can write game that can compile to a machine code that can work on Android. But I can't understand how it is being done. I know that to compile C++ code means to map the code written by a developer to CPU instructions for a concrete CPU. Now I compile C++ code on my Windows 7 and Intel processor. What role does Android NDK plays that the code compiled for my computer works on my Android phone?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the code isn't compiled *for* your computer, only *on* your computer. It's compiled for whatever platform you're targeting, most likely some ARM variant.